# Reading columns of MySQL table as separate JSON object

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I am reading data from a MySQL table like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $tmp[]=$row;
}
```

It reads whole row as a single item in the `tmp` array, but I want all values of a single column together in a separate array. e.g if I the table is:

```
     -------------------
      Honda  Suzuki  BMW
     -------------------
      Accord  Alto   abc
      Acty    Baleno xyz
```

I get this:

```
     [{"Honda":"Accord","Suzuki":"Alto","BMW":"abc"},
      {"Honda":"Acty","Suzuki":"Baleno","BMW":xyz"}]
```

but I want this:

```
     [ Honda:{Accord,Acty},
       Suzuki:{Alto,Baleno},
       BMW:{abc,xyz}
     ]
```

Can somebody tell how should I structure the data like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you mean

```
{ "Honda":["Accord","Acty"],
  "Suzuki":["Alto","Baleno"],
  "BMW":["abc","xyz"]
}
```

which you would get by

```
$tmp=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  foreach($row as $name=>$value)
    //Next 2 lines updated after input from comment
    if (!$value) continue;
    else if (!isset($tmp[$name])) $tmp[$name]=array($value);
    else $tmp[$name][]=$value;
$tmp=json_encode($tmp);
```

Comment: GREAT!!! Thanks alot. I was so stupid to keep wasting time on this. But your solution also includes null values. How can I avoid this e.g I want that if the value of a cell is null then it isn't included in the JSON data???

Comment: Updated my answer - I guessed you also want to suppress empty strings (not just NULL)